# Google Pie chart tooltip z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-pie-chart

I have a google pie chart where tooltips are rendered behind an adjacent image.

How can I make sure the tooltips are displayed on top?
I have set 0 for the images z-index,
10 for the overall chart 
but z-index is not working.

Here in image :

[image]

Comment: Demo or it didn't happen! :p It depends on the context and relationships of the elements, and whether they have positioning set, etc. Not answerable without the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try override tooltip css

```
.google-visualization-tooltip{
    z-index: 1000;
 }
```

I had the same problem, my tooltip hides behind custom legend.

Comment: It is noteworthy to mention that this seemed to only work for HTML tooltips, where `options` has `tooltip: { isHtml: true }` Didn't work for me when tooltips generated with the default SVG